# why is my input-Pixel in "r.resamp.filter" not always the center-pixel of the output?

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis

I struggle to understand the mechanics from `r.resamp.filter`. I create a raster in the projection EPSG 2056. with cell-size 1 around an arbitrary origin (here:

```
Extent  -8.1370000000000005,983.1934999999999718 : 19.8629999999999995,1021.1934999999999718
Dimensionen X: 28 Y: 38 Kanäle: 1
Origin  -8.1370000000000005,1021.1934999999999718
Pixel size  1,-1
```

All values are set to be 0 but three pixels (shown in red) are given the value 10.

I run `r.resamp.filter` from QGIS with a box filter and a Radius 3 (result shown as dark box around the red input-value)

Why is the input-pixel not always in the same place of the box? The upper two boxes have the dimensions 6 by 7 Pixels, the lower box 7 by 7.

[image]

I realized, that the radius is given in map units (https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/2569).

And if set the radius to 3.5, the result is as expected, with three boxes dimensioned 7 by 7.

[image]

Now, if I add a gaussian filter with radius 1.5, the box-filter with radius 3 yields a much broader smooth (left) than with a box-filter with radius 3.5 (right). Why is having a narrower box-filter yielding a broader smoothing?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but my guess is that the 6x7 box resampling results from rounding errors due to the way decimal numbers are represented in computers. (BTW, what's the use case for coordinate accuracy of 10e-12 ?? picometer ~= 1/2 the wavlength of light)

Comment: Ooops, the wavelength of light is 500,000 picometers. One helium atom is 100 picometers. Do you really need the region specified to that level of precision?? I think it will cause trouble whatever you do.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I was mapping bosons with qGIS... interesting interpretation of quantum computing ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I redid your procedure, but setting the region to **integer** values:

```
micha@RMS:~$ g.proj -p
-PROJ_INFO-------------------------------------------------
name       : CH1903+ / LV95
datum      : ch1903
ellps      : bessel
proj       : somerc
lat_0      : 46.9524055555556
lon_0      : 7.43958333333333
k_0        : 1
x_0        : 2600000
y_0        : 1200000
no_defs    : defined
-PROJ_SRID-------------------------------------------------
SRID       : EPSG:2056
-PROJ_UNITS------------------------------------------------
unit       : meter
units      : meters
meters     : 1

g.region -ap n=1021 s=983 w=-8 e=20
projection: 99 (CH1903+ / LV95)
zone:       0
datum:      ch1903
ellipsoid:  bessel
north:      1021
south:      983
west:       -8
east:       20
nsres:      1
ewres:      1
rows:       38
cols:       28
cells:      1064

r.mapcalc "one = 1"
r.random -s input=one npoints=3 raster=red --o
r.resamp.filter input=red out=box_filter radius=3 filter=box
```

Here's the result (box filters all the same size):
[image: Box filter]

Comment: many thanks! Did you do that in qGIS? I didn't realize that my region was defined in such a way and will pay attention to it if it causes future trouble.

Comment: No QGIS. The above commands were run in the GRASS console.